# position absolute element visible inside overflow:hidden element

Tags: css

I need to have elements positioned absolute inside a div with overflow hidden, however these elements with position absolute are visible outside the boundaries of the div with overflow hidden, I would need them not to be visible at all.
See code: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYJc/

The idea is:

- when you hover on one 'li' it will slide in (inside an iPhone frame) the respective picture
- this the CSS for each image

  ```
      .first .search{
          position: absolute;
          width: 229px;
          margin: 94px 60px 40px -280px;
          -webkit-transition:margin-left 0.3s ease-out;
          -webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
      }
  ```
- and this is the CSS for the container:

  ```
      .iPhoneWrapper div{
          overflow-x: hidden;
          margin-left: 17px;
      }
  ```

As it stands the '.search' positioned absolute is visible  outside the 'div' with overflow hidden and I need them to be hidden and only visible when sliding in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

add `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` to your class `.iPhoneWrapper`, modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYJc/1/